# Will compilers optimize double logical negation in conditionals?

Tags: c, optimization

Consider the following hypothetical type:

```
typedef struct Stack {
    unsigned long len;
    void **elements;
} Stack;
```

And the following hypothetical macros for dealing with the type (purely for enhanced readability.) In these macros I *am* assuming that the given argument has type (Stack *) instead of merely Stack (I can't be bothered to type out a _Generic expression here.)

```
#define stackNull(stack) (!stack->len)
#define stackHasItems(stack) (stack->len)
```

Why do I not simply use `!stackNull(x)` for checking if a stack has items? I thought that this would be slightly less efficient (read: not noticeable at all really, but I thought it was interesting) than simply checking `stack->len` because it would lead to double negation. In the following case:

```
int thingy = !!31337;
printf("%d\n", thingy);
if (thingy)
    doSomethingImportant(thingy);
```

The string "1\n" would be printed, and It would be impossible to optimize the conditional (well actually, only impossible if the thingy variable didn't have a constant initializer or was modified before the test, but we'll say in this instance that 31337 is not a constant) because `(!!x)` is guaranteed to be either `0` or `1`.

But I'm wondering if compilers will optimize something like the following

```
int thingy = wellOkaySoImNotAConstantThingyAnyMore();
if (!!thingy)
    doSomethingFarLessImportant();
```

Will this be optimized to actually just use (thingy) in the if statement, as if the `if` statement had been written as

```
if (thingy)
    doSomethingFarLessImportant();
```

If so, does it expand to `(!!!!!thingy)` and so on? (however this is a slightly different question, as this can be optimized in any case, `!thingy` is `!!!!!thingy` no matter what, just like `-(-(-(1))) = -1.)`

In the question title I said "compilers", by that I mean that I am asking if **any** compiler does this, however I am particularly interested in how GCC will behave in this instance as it is my compiler of choice.

Comment: Any compiler that *didn't* do this trivial optimization I would consider unacceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems like a pretty [reasonable optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizing_compiler) and a quick test using [godbolt](http://gcc.godbolt.org/) with this code (*[see it live](http://goo.gl/Xwcj9a)*):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func( int x)
{  
  if( !!x )
  {
    printf( "first\n" ) ;
  }

  if( !!!x )
  {
    printf( "second\n" ) ;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int x = 0 ;

  scanf( "%d", &x ) ;
  func( x ) ;
}
```

seems to indicate `gcc` does well, it generates the following:

```
func:
    testl   %edi, %edi  # x
    jne .L4 #,
    movl    $.LC1, %edi #,
    jmp puts    #
.L4:
    movl    $.LC0, %edi #,
    jmp puts    #
```

we can see from the first line:

```
testl   %edi, %edi  # x
```

it just uses `x` without doing any operations on it, also notice the optimizer is clever enough to combine both tests into one since if the first condition is `true` the other must be `false`.

Note I used `printf` and `scanf` for side effects to prevent the optimizer from optimizing all the code away.

Comment: In fact, even with `-O0` (optimizations turned off), my installed copy of gcc-4.8.3 produces identical code for `!x` and `!!!x`.